# Storing data on a user's Google's account

Tags: php, google-account

Is there any way in which a PHP powered web app can store data in a user's Google account? (after requesting permission from the user)

Basically I want to stay away from storing private user data on my server.

App will be handling mostly documents / text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the google docs api:
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

But if want private data for the app, you'll need to store it somewhere else than Google. With OpenAuth (or OpenID) you'd not need to worry about personal info.

Comment: right, so I could allow users to create stuff on my web app, then save as separate docs on their account, and locally I will just need to keep relations between these documents appropriately. correct ?

Comment: Yes you could be able to do that. The user will still be able to manipulate those docs outside of your application, but you might easily create a separate "folder" to mark them, so that the user will be distracted to do so.