# Google App Engine: Persist database content on a user's account

Tags: database, google-app-engine, persistence, google-cloud-datastore

Being new to Google App Engine, I've got a question related to this one:

[Storing data on a user's Google's account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708044/)

Here is what I actually want to do:

- Create an application using entirely Google App Engine and BigTable for persistence
- But I do not want to use my own App Engine account. Instead I want to use the user's account. For instance, an Android app should use the user's account for persisting its data, not that of the app programmer.

Is this possible all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your goal to use the user's quota for storage, rather than the application's?

You couldn't do this using App Engine's datastore (if that's what you mean by "BigTable for persistence") unless you did something really weird like have each user create their own App Engine app and communicate with it via REST.

However, you could think about using the [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/get_started) to store & retrieve data. Be aware that apps that use the Drive SDK must be installed via the Chrome Apps Store. Here's a [sample using App Engine](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Google drive is not quite what I've been looking for (and indeed, that *was* what I mean by "BigTable for persitence" ;-) ) However, I guess I've got to get along with Google drive for persisting user data. Great to get back to good old school flat file databasing :-D